# Failure to read full line including embedded zero bytes

Tags: file-io, input, lua

Lua script:

```
i=io.read()
print(i)
```

Command line:

```
echo -e "sala\x00m" | lua ll.lua
```

Output:

```
sala
```

I want it to print all character from input, similar to this:

```
salam
```

in HEX editor:

```
0000000: 7361 6c61 006d 0a                         sala.m.
```

How can I print all character from input?

Comment: Try `io.read'*a'` instead of `io.read()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tripped over one of the few places where the Lua standard library is still not 8-bit-clean.
Specifically, file reading line-by-line is not embedded-0 proof.

The reason it isn't yet is an unfortunate combination of:

- Only standard C90 or equally portable constructs are allowed for the core, which does not provide for efficient 0-clean text parsing.
- Every solution discussed to date on the mailinglist under that constraint has considerable overhead.
- Embedded 0-bytes in text files are quite rare.

Workarounds:

- Use a modified library, fixing these formats: `"*l"` `"*L"` for `file:read(...)`
- parse your raw data yourself. (read a block using a number or as much as possible using `"*a"`)
- Badger the Lua developers/maintainers for a bugfix until they give in.

Comment: I should also mention that Lua 5.1's `print()` *cannot* handle embedded NULLs whereas Lua 5.2's *can* handle them. This means that the asker's code won't work, on 5.1, even if he hadn't the `*l` deficiency.

Comment: @NiccoloM. Making sure everything is 8-bit clean is an ongoing campaign. There were more library functions which were not 0-proof back then (8 years ago), not only `print`. Imho `file:read` is special because no fix was accepted even though its brokenness is well known.